# How did Anakin describe killing Count Dooku to Obi-Wan/the Jedi Council?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Assuming that they asked him about something as momentous as the death of the Separatist Leader, one of the greatest swordsman in the galaxy, and a former Jedi Master, how did Anakin explain to Obi-Wan and/or the Jedi Council exactly why and how he ended up killing Count Dooku?

Answers from canon or Legends are welcome.

Comment: I'm assuming "We fought and I beheaded him" was sufficient explanation. Inquests for war criminals during wartime are usually pretty short.

Comment: @Valorum Well you can't label anyone a "war criminal" without an inquest. Jedi Council: Galactic Peace through Superior Swordspower.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - I'm reasonably sure that he would be recognised as a war criminal even prior to a fair trial.

Comment: “He’s too dangerous to be left alive”

Comment: The Supreme Chancellor, using his emergency authority granted by the Senate, ordered Dooku's summary execution by the Jedi General Anakin Skywalker. With the Chancellor as a witness, and the intsigator, to the act, not much needs to be explained.

Comment: @Daishozen I think that is almost an answer. He was ordered by Palpatine, seems explaination enough for the council.

Comment: @Daishozen - I very much doubt that either Anakin or Palpatine described that event. It would have been very worrying that Anakin had taken that order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization)) Palpatine and Anakin agree not to tell the truth about what happened.

> “And we won’t. Just as we need never speak of what has happened here today.” It was as though the shadow itself spoke kindly. “I have always kept your secrets, have I not?”

When asked what happened by Mace and the Jedi Council, Anakin demurs to the Chancellor who describes it as an epic lightsaber fight that ended with Anakin winning (e.g. killing Dooku).

> “Count Dooku was there,” Skywalker interjected. He had a look on his face that Mace couldn’t decipher, proud yet wary— even unhappy. “He’s dead now.”
>
> “Dead?” He looked from Anakin to Obi-Wan and back again. “Is this true? You killed Count Dooku?”
>
> “My young friend is too modest; he killed Count Dooku.” Smiling, Kenobi touched the lump on his head. “I was … taking a nap.”
>
> “But …” Mace blinked. Dooku was to the Separatists what Palpatine was to the Republic: the center of gravity binding together a spiral galaxy of special interests. With Dooku gone, the Confederacy of Independent Systems would no longer really be a confederacy at all. They’d fly to pieces within weeks.
>
> Within days.
>
> Mace said again, “But …”
>
> And, in the end, he couldn’t think of a but.
>
> This was all so astonishing that he very nearly-almost, but not quite-cracked a smile.
>
> “That is,” he said, “the best news I’ve heard since …” He shook his head. “Since I can’t remember. Anakin-how did you do it?”
>
> Inexplicably, young Skywalker looked distinctly uncomfortable; that newly confident presence of his collapsed as suddenly as an overloaded deflector, and instead of meeting Mace’s eyes, his gaze flicked to Palpatine. Somehow Mace didn’t think this was modesty. He looked to the Chancellor as well, his elation sinking, becoming puzzlement tinged with suspicion.
>
> “It was … entirely extraordinary,” Palpatine said blandly, oblivious to Mace’s narrowing stare. “I know next to nothing of swordplay, of course; to my amateur’s eye, it seemed that Count Dooku may have been … a trace overconfident. Especially after having disposed of Master Kenobi so neatly.”
>
> Obi-Wan flushed, just a bit-and Anakin flushed considerably more deeply.
>
> “Perhaps young Anakin was simply more … highly motivated,” Palpatine said, turning a fond smile upon him. “After all, Dooku was fighting only to slay an enemy; Anakin was fighting to save-if I may presume the honor-a friend.”

Anakin is then pressed by Mace to provide "*a full report*", but there's no reason to assume he didn't tell the same story; he and Obi-Wan engaged Dooku, Dooku knocked Obi-Wan unconscious, they fought and the fight ended with Dooku's death.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really interesting stuff, seeing Palpatine stirring the pot so effectively.

Comment: @Phyneas - I do genuinely recommend the official novelisation for Revenge of the Sith. Very well written and it offers a lot of good insight into the planning and plotting that's going on behind the scenes